# How to detect the first run of an IteratorProtocol in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, fibonacci, iterator-protocol

Trying to detect the first run of an Iterator protocol.
In the example below I'm trying to start printing Fibonacci series from Zero but it starts from One:

```
class FibIterator : IteratorProtocol {
var (a, b) = (0, 1)

func next() -> Int? {
    (a, b) = (b, a + b)
    return a
}
}

let fibs = AnySequence{FibIterator()}

print(Array(fibs.prefix(10)))
```

What modifications can be made to the above code to detect the first run?

Comment: Just a note that an infinite sequence like this can lead to infinite loops. Something to keep in mind when passing the sequence around :)

Comment: Thank you @Cristik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your verbatim question: You can add a boolean variable
`firstRun` to detect the first call of the `next()` method:

```
class FibIterator : IteratorProtocol {
    var firstRun = true
    var (a, b) = (0, 1)

    func next() -> Int? {
        if firstRun {
            firstRun = false
            return 0
        }
        (a, b) = (b, a + b)
        return a
    }
}

let fibs = AnySequence { FibIterator() }
print(Array(fibs.prefix(10))) // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

But there are more elegant solutions for this problem.
You can “defer” the update of `a` and `b` to be done *after* returning
the current value:

```
class FibIterator : IteratorProtocol {
    var (a, b) = (0, 1)

    func next() -> Int? {
        defer { (a, b) = (b, a + b) }
        return a
    }
}

let fibs = AnySequence { FibIterator() }
print(Array(fibs.prefix(10))) // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

or – perhaps simpler – change the initial values (using the fact
that the Fibonacci numbers are defined for negative indices as well):

```
class FibIterator : IteratorProtocol {
    var (a, b) = (1, 0)  // (Fib(-1), Fib(0))

    func next() -> Int? {
        (a, b) = (b, a + b)
        return a
    }
}

let fibs = AnySequence { FibIterator() }
print(Array(fibs.prefix(10))) // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Note that if you declare conformance to the `Sequence` protocol
then you don't need the `AnySequence` wrapper (there is a default
implementation of `makeIterator()` for types conforming to
`IteratorProtocol`). Also value types are generally preferred,
so – unless the reference semantics is needed – you can make it a `struct`:

```
struct FibSequence : Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    var (a, b) = (1, 0)  // (Fib(-1), Fib(0))

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        (a, b) = (b, a + b)
        return a
    }
}

let fibs = FibSequence()
```